# I want to move links from bottom of sidebar to top

Tags: button, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar, google-apps-script-editor

I created a sidebar in Google Sheets using an online template. It is working perfectly, but the buttons to update and reset are on the bottom, and I would like them on top of the sidebar list.

I have tried altering the button code in terms of height and other factors but cannot seem to get it to be agreeable.

This is where I believe the code needs to be altered:

```
.button,
button,
input[type="button"],
input[type="image"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f1f1f1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f1f1f1);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f1f1f1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f1f1f1);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f1f1f1);
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #333;
  cursor: default;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 29px;
  line-height: 27px;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 72px;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0 8px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

<body>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <p>
            <button class="action" id="action">Add Rejections</button>
            <button id="btn">Reset List</button>
        </p>
    </div>
```

I would ultimately like the two buttons to be on top of the sidebar list instead of having to scroll to the bottom. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry! I figured it out. Ended up having to change a different spot. If anyone is interested in the solution I will post it.

Comment: Good to know it's working now, you should post it for documentation!